# How to create a shortcut to an entry of group policy editor in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

How can I create a shortcut on my desktop to open group policy editor in a specific entry?

Details:
I want to open Gpedit and drill down to a setting automatically.

Comment: So you don't want to open Gpedit and drill down to a setting? Just open gpedit and jump to the setting using a shortcut?, No I don't think you can.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to accomplish.

Comment: FWIW, SysInternals Autoruns has a feature that accomplishes this for the Registry; it opens Regedit then drills down to the targeted value. Perhaps an AHK script could do it.